# python network threading simple chat, waits for user to press enter then gets messages

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-2.7, python-3.x

so right now in order to receive your message you need to receive one

my teachers instructions are (in the main)"Modify the loop so that it only listens for keyboard input and then sends it to the server."
I did the rest but don't understand this, ... help?

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import threading

'''
Purpose:  Driver
parameters: none
returns: none
'''

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 5000
    size = 1024
    #open a socket to the client.
    try:
        clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSock.connect((host,port))
        #exit on error
    except socket.error, (value,message):
        if clientSock :
            clientSock.close()
            print "Could not make connection: " + message
        sys.exit(1) 

    thread1 = ClientThread() 
    thread1.start() 

    while True:
        #wait for keyboard input
        line = raw_input()
        #send the input to the server unless its only a newline
        if line != "\n":
            clientSock.send(line)
        #wait to get something from the server and print it
        data = clientSock.recv(size)
        print data
class ClientThread(threading.Thread): 

 ''' 
 Purpose: the constructor 
 parameters: the already created and connected client socket 
 returns: none 
 ''' 

def __init__(self, clientSocket): 
    super(ClientThread, self).__init__() 
    self.clientSocket = clientSocket 
    self.stopped = False 



def run(self): 
    while not self.stopped: 
        self.data = self.clientSocket.recv(1024) 
        print self.data 



main()
```

Comment: shouldn't be that complicated any more information I can give?

Comment: could you describe what's the supposed behavior of this program? and what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your purpose is to create a program that starts two threads, one (client thread) receives keyboard input and sends to the other (server thread), the server thread prints out everything it received.

Based on my assumption, you first need to start a ServerThread listen to a port (it's not like what your 'ClientThread' did). Here's an example:

```
import socket
import threading

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 5000
    size = 1024

    thread1 = ServerThread(host, port, size) 
    thread1.start() 

    #open a socket for client
    try:
        clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSock.connect((host,port))
    except socket.error, (value,message):
        if clientSock:
            clientSock.close()
            print "Could not connect to server: " + message
        sys.exit(1) 

    while True:
        #wait for keyboard input
        line = raw_input()
        #send the input to the server unless its only a newline
        if line != "\n":
            clientSock.send(line)
            # Is server supposed to send back any response?
            #data = clientSock.recv(size)
            #print data
        if line == "Quit":
            clientSock.close()
            break

class ServerThread(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self, host, port, size): 
        super(ServerThread, self).__init__() 
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((host, port))
        self.sock.listen(1)
        self.data_size = size
        self.stopped = False 

    def run(self): 
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
        print 'Connected by', addr
        while not self.stopped: 
            data = conn.recv(self.data_size)
            if data == 'Quit':
                print 'Client close the connection'
                self.stopped = True
            else:
                print 'Server received data:', data
                # Is server supposed to send back any response?
                #conn.sendall('Server received data: ' + data)
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And these are the output:

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 41153)
abc
Server received data: abc
def
Server received data: def
Quit
Client close the connection
```

You may check here for more details about Python socket: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?#example